# Adding a unique constraint on calculated value of a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this, but here goes...
We have a table structure like the following:

```
Id   |   Timestamp    | Type  | Clientid   | ..others..
001  |   1234567890   | TYPE1 | CL1234567  |.....    
002  |   1234561890   | TYPE1 | CL1234567  |.....
```

Now for the data given above... I would like to have a constraint so that those 2 rows could not exist together. Essentially, I want the table to be

```
Unique for (Type, ClientId, CEIL(Timestamp/10000)*10000)
```

I don't want rows with the same data created within X time of each other to be added to the db, i.e would like a constraint violation in this case. The problem is that, the above constraint is not something I can actually create.

Before you ask, I know, I know.... why right? Well I know a certain scenario should not be happening, but alas it is. I need a sort of stop gap measure for now, so I can buy some time to investigate the actual matter. Let me know if you need additional info...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Oracle supports calculated columns:

```
SQL> alter table test add calc_column as (trunc(timestamp/10000));

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test
     add constraint test_uniq
     unique (type, clientid, calc_column);

Table altered.
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Similar issue as above, but if I do have to add a new column, this looks like the way to go. I like the idea of using trunc instead of what I was doing (1 less math op). Now to see if the db folks find this copacetic.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Oracle does not support computed columns like SQL Server does. You can mimic the functionality of a computed column using Triggers.

Here are the steps for this

1. Add a column called `CEILCalculation` to your table.

   - On your table, put a trigger will update `CEILCalculation` with the value from `CEIL(Timestamp/10000)*10000`
   - Create a Unique Index on the three columns `(Unique for (Type, ClientId, CEILCalculation)`

If you do not want to modify the table structure, you can put a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on the table and check for validity over there.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php

Comment: Thx for the quick info... I thought of this too... I'd like to avoid adding columns etc, and modifying the schema too much. The issue is that the table is ginormous and often used/updated